# DAViCal Free/busy information for email aliases

Tags: caldav

I have system users with short usernames but they all have email aliases
 <first-name>.<last-name>@example.com .

Davical locates the calendar and free/busy information by email address, that is the
<username>@example.com .

How do I configure DAViCal so people can book meetings with the long email-adress?